# Modify YouTube Embed Code to fit theme

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, embed, responsive, youtube

I'm using a custom bootstrap template and other users will be embedding youtube videos, which I want to be responsive to fit the theme.

What can I do to make the normal YouTube embed code, something like this:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/2jna3dWEnzo" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Into this formatting (simplified and with class added):

```
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/2jna3dWEnzo" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Any help would be fab!

Comment: Making the iframe responsive can be done using CSS, you don't need to change the markup of the embed code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the block editor, the fix is simple:

```php
add_theme_support( 'responsive-embeds' );
```

You can also make the iframe responsive using pure CSS, just wrap it in a `div`:

```
<div class="yt-container">
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2jna3dWEnzo
</div>
```

```css
    .yt-container {
      position:relative;
      padding-bottom:56.25%;
      padding-top:30px;
      height:0;
      overflow:hidden;
    }
    .yt-container iframe, .yt-container object, .yt-container embed {
      position:absolute;
      top:0;
      left:0;
      width:100%;
      height:100%;
    }
```

This article covers making embeds responsive using CSS and JS:

https://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-video/